# Can I access to the business lounges during the layover?

Tags: layovers, connecting-flights, lufthansa, lounges, business-class

I have a business class ticket for my flight with Lufthansa from Venice and I have a connecting flight from Frankfurt. Then my other flight is in Economy class with Sunexpress. Can I still access to Lufthansa lounge in Frankfurt Airport using the (old) business boarding pass even after I arrived there? Or I can't access there because my next departure is not Business class anymore?

Answer (score 3):

Probably not.

Lufthansa Rules are notoriously complicated and at the moment there doesn't seem to be anything published officially. At least I couldn't find it.

A recent trip report that was a similar case was denied access, since lounge access through class of service is determined by the departing ticket, not the arriving (or the whole itinerary).

https://yourmileagemayvary.net/2022/04/23/why-not-allowed-luftansa-lounge/

If this is on a single ticket you can certainly walk up to the counter and ask. See what happens. If these are two separate tickets, the answer is no.

Comment: Agreed. On the other hand, Lufthansa often advertised post-flight shower and lounge access to me (before covid). It probably depends on the mood of the person at the entry.

Comment: Today I called the customer service of Lufthansa and asked if i could use the lounge after my arrival and they said Yes. Since sunexpress is owned by Lufthansa i guess.